# Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence. Show that $y_n = n(x_{n+1} - x_n)$ can't have limit $+ \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have tried to solve this problem by supposing by contradiction that the limit was  $ + \infty$. Then, you'd have $\forall M > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n > N, n(x_{n+1} - x_n) > M$. This would mean that $(x_n)$ is increasing after a certain order $N$, which means that it must be convergent. I don't know how to continue past this point.

Comment: A special case of the "[general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#The_general_form)" of Stolz–Cesàro theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} n(x_{n+1}-x_n) = +\infty$$then there exists $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$,
$$n(x_{n+1}-x_n) \geq 1, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad x_{n+1}-x_n \geq \frac{1}{n}$$

If you sum that from $N$ to an integer $N'$ you get
$$\sum_{n=N}^{N'} x_{n+1}-x_n \geq \sum_{n=N}^{N'} \frac{1}{n}$$

i.e

$$x_{N'+1} \geq x_N +\sum_{n=N}^{N'} \frac{1}{n}$$

Now, let $N'$ tend to $+\infty$ : you get that
$$\lim_{n' \rightarrow +\infty} x_{N'} = +\infty$$

which is absurd.

Comment: This proof only requires $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(x_{n+1}-x_n)>0$, right?

Comment: @KentaS Yes, indeed. And also, the hypothesis that the sequence is bounded can be changed into the weaker one "the sequence does not tend to $+\infty$".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n(x_{n+1}-x_n)>M>0$ for all $n>N$.
Then
$$ x_{n+1}>x_{N+1}+M\sum_{k=N+1}^n \frac 1k$$
for all $n>N$.